# google play publish issue with wrong questionnaire

Tags: android, google-play

I tried to publish app on google play, but I get this error:

```
Your app submission has been rejected for a violation of the Google Play Developer Program Policy regarding Content Ratings. If this submission was an update to an existing app, the version published prior to this update is still available in Google Play. Please review the content rating guidelines help article, then retake the content rating questionnaire and resubmit. Additional details have been sent to your account owner's email address.
```

[image]

I understand that I need to change app range and start new questionnaire, but this button is disabled. What should I do?

Comment: I think resume link is one you need.

Comment: thank you very much, you can post the answer I will accept it

Comment: same problem i got in app. app rejected and  don't know in questionnaire which i give wrong answer..so what i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a pending questionnaire which you can access with the resume link from your screenshot.